# How to read a file from a Maven dependency project?

Tags: java, maven

I have two Maven projects A and B. B depends on A.

In A, I have a file `someFile.txt` in the `src/main/resources` folder.

```
public class SomeAClass
{
    public void someMethod()
    {
        final InputStream inputStream =
                Thread.currentThread()
                        .getContextClassLoader()
                        .getResourceAsStream("someFile.txt");
        final List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(inputStream);

        ...
    }
}
```

In A's tests, this works fine.

Now imagine I want to use that same code in B, including the ability to read the data from `src/main/resources/someFile.txt`.

Right now, calling `SomeAClass.someMethod()` from project B causes a NullPointerException and I suspect it's because `src/main/resources/someFile.txt` cannot be found.

How can I change the code for getting the input stream for `src/main/resources/someFile.txt` so that it works both in A's unit tests and when executing B (B is a Spring Shell based console application) ?

Comment: Are you running this code from IDE?

Comment: No, I run `mvn clean package`, then run the resulting Spring Shell app using `java -jar target/myjar.jar`. This is where the NPE occurs.

Comment: You have  2 jars, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. For A, I do `mvn clean install`, which puts A's JAR into the local Maven repository. B has a dependency on A in `pom.xml`. Right now, I'm not on the machine where I build it so I can't say whether A's JAR is embedded into B's JAR.

Comment: I think myjar.jar does not contain someFile.txt.  Try to view myjar.jar

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev Let's assume you are right. How could I fix it? For example, when building a JAR, I can tell Maven to include all dependencies into it. Is there something similar for my case?

Comment: You can build jar-with-dependencies (see assembly plugin). Or you can add A.jar to classpath java -cp A.jar -jar target/myjar.jar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure that the problem is there, because I have a similar approach and it works right.

**That was my first attempt**

If you are using someFile.txt as a resource in your tests (and only there, if you are using in your main project, ignore the post), instead of using `src/main/resources`, maybe it would be better to put that file and others which are used in `src/test/resources`.

**But**

If you put these test files in `src/test/resources`, remember that the test resources are not contained in the project artifact, so you can not access them althoug you include the dependency in your pom.

**What I did (something like yours)**

Create new module (test-resources) and put the resources in `src/main/resources`. The module is used as dependency in the projects I need with test scope. But what I used was ClassPathResource.

```
    ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("the_file"); 
    resource.getInputStream()
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you post here the code, which you use to read the file (analogous in purpose to `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("someFile.txt")`) ?

Comment: ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("the_file"); resource.getInputStream()

Comment: Using `ClassPathResource` actually solved the problem.